# Playing video Ads with VAST2.0 on Cordova\Phonegap application

Tags: cordova, mobile-website, vast, mobfox

I'm developing Application on PhoneGap\Cordova platform, and willing to integrate MobFox video ads.

I'm trying to play video-ad, when getting a VAST 2.0 XML from MobFox ad-server, But can't figure out how...

Test Ad URL:
"http://my.mobfox.com/request.php?rt=api&r_type=video&r_resp_vast20&s=80187188f458cfde788d961b6882fd53&i=2.122.29.194&u=Mozilla/5.0%20%28iPhone;%20U;%20CPU%20iPhone%20OS%203_0%20like%20Mac%20OS%20X;%20en-us%29%20AppleWebKit/528.18%20%28KHTML,%20like%20Gecko%29%20Version/4.0%20Mobile/7A341%20Safari/528.16&o_iosadvid=68753A44-4D6F-1226-9C60-0050E4C00067"

Will be glad for any help or direction!

Comment: Have you integrated the vast tags in Phonegap based mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the MobFox official guideline, no need to handle the XML, just call the API. See the java example code for android:

```
mManager = new AdManager(this, "http://my.mobfox.com/request.php","ENTER_PUBLISHER_ID_HERE", true);
mManager.setListener(this);
mManager.setInterstitialAdsEnabled(true); //enabled by default. Allows the SDK to request static interstitial ads.
mManager.setVideoAdsEnabled(true); //disabled by default. Allows the SDK to request video fullscreen ads.
mManager.setPrioritizeVideoAds(true); //disabled by default. If enabled, indicates that SDK should request video ads first, and only if there is no video request an interstitial (if enabled)
mManager.requestAd();
```